# PowerPivot doesn't refresh data whether it says "refreshed succesfully"

Tags: excel, sql-server-2012, powerpivot

I use PowerPivot to connect to SQL Views on MS SQL Server 2012 (Office 2013 edition). I've mapped the view into PowerPivot and it works ok. If I click on REFRESH ALL it starts refreshing and says "successfully completed". But it doesn't refresh anything actually - I know that the view should have like 10000 rows, but the table in PowerPivot still shows only 5000 rows (which was the initial count of rows in the view).

Any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Michal

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Open powerpivot, go to table properties, and make sure that there are no filters (clear row filters) and that all columns are selected. for example, if you modify your table/view in SQL and add a new column, this will appear unchecked in the table properties. Very wrong choice by Microsoft, and very poorly documented!